# How to add UI to the windows8.1 window (C++/CX)

Tags: windows-8.1, c++-cx

I've got the most simple windows store program. It just runs the white-color window till the Quit (as well as the most simple Win32 application would do).

```
ref class ApplicationViewSource sealed : IFrameworkViewSource {
public:
    virtual IFrameworkView^ CreateView() {
        return ref new WindowsStoreApp::MainView();
    }


};

[MTAThread]
int main(Array<String^>^ args) {
    CoreApplication::Run(ref new ApplicationViewSource());
    return 0;
}

ref class MainView sealed : IFrameworkView {
    public:
        virtual void Initialize(CoreApplicationView^ AppView);
        virtual void SetWindow(CoreWindow^ Window);
        virtual void Load(String^ EntryPoint);
        virtual void Run();
        virtual void Uninitialize();

        void OnActivated(CoreApplicationView^, IActivatedEventArgs^);
    };

void MainView::Initialize(CoreApplicationView^ AppView) {
        AppView->Activated += ref new TypedEventHandler<CoreApplicationView^, IActivatedEventArgs^>(this, &MainView::OnActivated);
    }

    void MainView::SetWindow(CoreWindow^ window) {
        window->PointerCursor = ref new CoreCursor(CoreCursorType::Hand, 0);

    }

    void MainView::Load(String^ EntryPoint) {
    }

    void MainView::Run() {
        CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->Dispatcher->ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption::ProcessUntilQuit);
    }

    void MainView::Uninitialize() {
    }

    void MainView::OnActivated(CoreApplicationView^, IActivatedEventArgs^) {
        CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->Activate();
    }
```

So... **What I need to do next ?**  As for Win32 project I could create some graphical user interface components with CreateWindow(Ex) function as windows of the specific window-classes. With the windows store app API I can't figure out how to add any visuals.
Manual only gives hints about adding ones with code to existing XAML page, allready been connected to the window.

Comment: Like with classic Win32 Desktop applications, that use either resource scripts or manual `CreateWindowEx` calls, a Windows Store app can either use XAML or manual `ref new` calls to construct it's UI. Since the C++/WinRT project doesn't support XAML yet, you'll find lots of [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/tree/master/10.0.14393.0/Samples) dynamically constructing their UI. (You need to be able to translate C++/WinRT code into C++/CX code to use those samples.)

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks a lot! I've walked through samples, they are useful ones.